# Filter Two DataGridViews bound to the same DataTable

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview, filter

Windows Form Application, c#-4.0

I have two DataGridViews in one form, they are both bound to the same DataSet and Table and I need to filter each DataGridView for separate values.

DataGridView 1 is `dgvSerials` and DataGridView 2 is `dgvAssignedSerials`, for `dgvAssignedSerials` I need to show all records were the ***column stat == "I" OR "O"*** and for `dgvSerials` I need to show all records where the ***column stat != "I" OR "O"***

My code so far. (Note: so far I have only attempted to filter the dgvAssignedSerials grid.)

```
    string serialFilter = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", "stat", "I");
    serialFilter += string.Format(" OR [{0}] = '{1}'", "stat", "O");
    (dgvAssignedSerials.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = serialFilter;
```

Also, I want to hide the *stat* column, not sure if that will affect the filter function.

Now, with the above code my application simply *finishes* on the `(dgvAssignedSerials.DataSource` line. If I put break points on that line and the next line, it never get's to that next line. There are no errors, it just finishes and displays the form and the DataGridView is not filtered.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I have this figured out.

When I posted this question, I was trying to execute my filter *after* I had bound my DataGridViews to their sources, and I was trying to do everything within the form load event. Not sure if the later was part of the issue, but I think why it wasn't working for me was, I was trying to filter after I had bound my DataGridViews.

To solve this I did the following.

First, I created a separate function in which to bind and filter each `DataGridView` and second, I first declared a `DataView`, filtered that `DataView`, then bound my `DataGridView` to the filtered `DataView`.

DataGridView 1 example:

```
    string serialFilter = string.Format("stat IN ('P', 'N')");
    DataView dvSerials = new DataView(_dtSerial);
    dvSerials.RowFilter = serialFilter;
    dgvSerials.DataSource = dvSerials;
```

DataGridView 2 example:

```
    string assignSerFilter = string.Format("stat IN ('I', 'O')");
    DataView dvAssignedSerials = new DataView(_dtSerial);
    dvAssignedSerials.RowFilter = assignSerFilter;
    dgvAssignedSerials.DataSource = dvAssignedSerials;
```

It works like a charm now.